# How to save a file using FormBuilderFilePicker and Isar - Flutter

Tags: flutter, file-upload, flutter-form-builder, flutter-isar

I'm working on a form where you enter a patient's data such as name, age, gender, etc... and an image gallery, I'm working with Isar, this the model

```
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';

part 'paciente.g.dart';

@collection
class Paciente {
  Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;
  String namep = '';
  String apellido1p = '';
  String apellido2p = '';
  int edadp = 0;
  String sexop = '';
  String numtelefp = '';
  String examenesp = '';
  String tratamientop = '';
  List<String>? imagenesp = [];
}
```

I made the form with the flutter_form_builder package and in the case of the images to upload them I used form_builder_file_picker

```
FormBuilderFilePicker(
                  // controller: selcimgPcontroller,
                  name: 'selcimgP',
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Adjuntar archivo",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(4.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  maxFiles: null,
                  allowMultiple: true,
                  previewImages: true,
                  onChanged: (val) => debugPrint(val.toString()),
                   typeSelectors: const [
                    TypeSelector(
                      type: FileType.image,
                      selector: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.file_upload),
                          Text('Subir archivos'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                 
                  
                ),
```

and at the end of the form use a button to later publish a list of the names and other data, in this case the name will only be displayed on another screen

```
ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        const SnackBar(
                          content: Text('Procesando Informacion'),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    Paciente paciente = Paciente()
                      ..namep = namePcontroller.text
                      ..apellido1p = apellido1Pcontroller.text
                      ..apellido2p = apellido2Pcontroller.text
                      ..edadp = int.parse(edadPcontroller.text)
                      ..sexop = _selectedValue
                      ..numtelefp = numtelefPcontroller.text
                      ..examenesp = examPcontroller.text
                      ..tratamientop = tratamientoPcontroller.text;
                    final id = await dao.upsert(paciente);
                    paciente.id = id;
                    namePcontroller.clear();
                    setState(() {
                      pacientes.add(paciente);
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Text('Guardar'),
                ),
```

In the previous code, the images are missing, so it would be something like `..imagenesp:xxxxxxxxx`
In this case it's what I don't know how to put it.
If you have any proposals I'm all ears, the tutorials and documents I've consulted work with `List<Uint8List>`But every time I try to put that in, I get wrong

If you have any ideas on how to help me I would appreciate it